# Working of Montgomery Ladder

Tags: number-theory

Can anybody explain the working of Montgomery Ladder and its efficiency in non cryptic language?
I have searched it but the notations are too cryptic for me.

Comment: What does it do?

Comment: speed up scalar multiplication...used for calculating exponents in logarithmic time....

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, not my area.

Comment: Please improve your question. provide citation of Montgomery Ladder.

Answer (score 3):

The purpose of [Mongomery Ladder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring#Montgomery.27s_ladder_technique) is in some way to be *less* than optimally efficient. It does so by permorming one multiplication and one squaring per bit of the exponent, no matter if that bit is a one or a zero.
This is slightly wasteful as one could save one operation for each zero bit.
So why waste time? Because an attacker who measures the time needed to calculate the exponentiation could infer how many operations are performed and hence could make a guess at the number of zero bits in the exponent. By even closer inspection, it might be possible to even determine more detailed information from things like power consumption or electromagnetic radiation patterns (I once had an old computer next to an old radio and one could really *hear* the difference between a long memcopy operation, a complicated mathematical calculation, and a keyboard wait loop) that differ between a normal multiplication and a squaring operation; in that case the attacker could in fact "hear" the exponent's exact bit pattern.